# Streamlit conditional formatting for rows in a table

Tags: ag-grid, conditional-formatting, streamlit

I'm trying to add conditional formatting to table rows in my [streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) app. Using  [streamlit-aggrid](https://github.com/PablocFonseca/streamlit-aggrid) package for it, for now, I found a way to format the table only per-column, for example:

```
gb = GridOptionBuilder.from_dataframe(mydf)
jscode = JsCode("""
function(params) {
    if (params.value > 70) {
        return {
            'color': 'white'
            'backgroundColor': '#fa7e74'
        }
    } else {
        return {
            'color': 'black'
            'backgroundColor': '#cdf6df'
        }
    }
};
""")
gb.configure_columns(mydf.columns[col_list], cellStyle=jscode, editable=True)
gridOptions = gb.build()
AgGrid(mydf,gridOptions=gridOptions,allow_unsafe_jscode=True)
```

I want to get something like this:
[image]

Comment: There are `getRowStyle` and `rowCssClasses` callbacks inside the `gridOptions` object in the JavaScript version of `ag-grid`. The python port should have something similar. JS Doc: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-styles/

Comment: @naveen thanks for the answer, but I believe that `getRowStyle` applies one style to the whole row

Comment: Ah okay. Got the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article on [medium](https://medium.com/@dmytrotarasevych/conditional-formatting-tables-in-streamlit-ad8ce83c4038) how to make it with Seaborn:

```
# Set CSS properties for th elements in dataframe
th_props = [
        ('font-size', '15px'),
        ('text-align', 'center'),
        ('font-weight', 'bold'),
        ('color', '#6d6d6d'),
        ('backgroud-color', '#f7ffff')
        ]

#Set table styles
styles = [
        dict(selector="th", props=th_props)
        ]

#Set colormap equal to seaborn light green color palette
cm = sns.light_palette('green', as_cmap=True)


table_to_render = (mydf.style
        .background_gradient(cmap=cm, axis=1)
        .set_caption('This is custom caption.')
        .format(na_rep = 'No data', precision=2, thousands=',')
        .highlight_null(null_color='white')
        .set_table_styles(styles))
st.table(table_to_render)
```